# CSS selector for html element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

At first I understand both Xpath and CSS selector notation are different.
http://ejohn.org/blog/xpath-css-selectors/

Basically I need to generate html element CSS selector on mousover.

(to make you understand generate Xpath or specifically CSS selector of the Html element on mouseover on an element).
I tried with event.data.selector 
Is there any api or sample code

Answer (score 5):

The selector for mouseover specifically is to append `:hover` in your CSS document.

So if you wanted to have a hover for an element with an ID of "hoverDiv", you would have something like this:

```
#hoverDiv:hover { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: thanks krillgar..
But my requirement is to get css selector on the mouseover on html elements

Comment: `:hover` will apply the entire time that the mouse is over the element. When the mouse leaves the element, it will no longer apply.

Comment: @user3395710: Are you saying on mouseover, you want to actually be able to acquire what CSS selector is driving the mouseover effect and return that? So, using krillgar's css, on mouseover of `#hoverDiv` you want to _return the selector string_ `#hoverDiv:hover` as indicating that _that_ selector is what is applying to the element at that moment of mouseover? That's about the only way I can interpret your comment in light of krillgar's answer, but you need to definitely clarify your question if my understanding noted here is correct (or if it is not, either way more clarity appears needed).

Comment: thanks scott and krillgar.. my need is similiar to xpath of an element i would like find an element using css selector.

Comment: Are you saying you need to use CSS to select which element has been moused over? That you can't do. You'll need javascript for that.